# Middleware paramaters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

[From the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters) I can see that to pass a parameter `editor` to a middleware `role` you write

```
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:editor', function ($id) {
    ...
}]);
```

And to use the parameter in the middleware, you simply pass the parameter into the handle function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    ...
}
```

My question is, where is this `editor` parameter coming from? I can only see the `id` in the URL string being passed about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$role` variable within the handle parameters will contain the variable passed in after `role:`

so `role:editor` will return `"editor"`

Comment: so it literally is the string 'editor' being passed to the middleware's handle function?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the role parameter. `editor` can be `admin`, `user`, `moderator` etc, then this value is passed to handle method. For more detailed information see this link: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/passing-parameters-to-middleware-in-laravel-5.1

Comment: I looked at that resource already, still wasn't any clearer that the official docs